# Magento 2 - Remove option for same biling and shipping

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address

I have a site which requires **all customers** to enter a different **shipping and billing** address. I know a little strange but all orders will have a different shipping and billing.

The problem I have is that I have **lazy customers** who just **tick the box**, but I need both shipping and billing to be filled in.

Is there a way to **remove the checkbox** and have the **billing address form visible**? I have tried writing a module but couldn't get it to work. Is there an easy solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: "I need both shipping and billing to be filled in." is different from "different shipping and billing address" can you specify which it is?

Comment: Hi Philipp, first and foremost, thanks so much for your reply. I require the customer to fill in both the shipping and billing address. The problem is that every order will have a different billing address compared to shipping address, so i need the checkbox to be removed that gives the customer the option to copy the shipping address over the the billing address.

Comment: Following link will be helpful to you .https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/170855/60921

Comment: Hi ARUNPRABAKARAN M, Unfrotunatley I have followed those steps but the tick box remains and is also by default selected.